# No root file system is defined error after installation

Tags: 11.04, windows-7, grub2

I installed ubuntu through Wubi and once i rebooted I get no root file system defined error. here's the output of the boot_info_script.Could anyone point me out where the error is.

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.60    from 17 May 2011


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe 
                       /ntldr /ntdetect.com /wubildr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr 
                       /wubildr.mbr /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr 
                       /ubuntu/disks/root.disk /ubuntu/disks/swap.disk

sda1/Wubi: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:  
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot.ini /ntldr /NTDETECT.COM

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7
    Boot sector info:   No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
240 heads, 63 sectors/track, 20673 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *             63   301,250,879   301,250,817   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2         301,250,943   312,575,759    11,324,817   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1  323,465,741,313,502,988275,962,973,585-323,465,465,350,529,402 -
/dev/sda2  242,728,591,638,290,720578,721,383,108,845,578335,992,791,470,554,859 -
/dev/sda3  1,827,498,311,425,204,2562,091,935,274,843,009,907264,436,963,417,805,652 -
/dev/sda4  579,711,218,081,401,3572,006,665,459,744,645,1521,426,954,241,663,243,796 -
/dev/sda11 270,286,346,402,038,1183,786,543,326,404,525,9543,516,256,980,002,487,837 -
/dev/sda12 4,179,681,002,230,769,6684,179,389,374,010,033,387-291,628,220,736,280 -
/dev/sda13 232,556,480,979,456,1311,160,152,593,793,119,235927,596,112,813,663,105 -
/dev/sda14 98,342,784,050,266,9183,691,264,578,843,725,1953,592,921,794,793,458,278 -
/dev/sda15 2,307,845,219,957,882,4961,850,841,032,955,276,350-457,004,187,002,606,145 -
/dev/sda16 512,592,046,878,946,497368,458,231,024,779,444-144,133,815,854,167,052 -
/dev/sda17 2,504,135,232,870,384,3923,665,087,872,719,320,8291,160,952,639,848,936,438 -
/dev/sda18 3,783,181,605,270,691,304122,034,509,624,708,942-3,661,147,095,645,982,361 -
/dev/sda19 3,519,661,520,275,829,5122,376,243,094,723,723,587-1,143,418,425,552,105,924 -
/dev/sda20 3,867,920,076,859,0744,494,691,111,933,625,1044,490,823,191,856,766,031 -
/dev/sda21 1,500,144,061,909,253,7612,511,182,033,846,676,3401,011,037,971,937,422,580 -
/dev/sda22 13,035,625,499,900,0062,360,168,613,941,394,9472,347,132,988,441,494,942 -
/dev/sda23 4,228,978,682,068,599,48813,159,423,631,648,263-4,215,819,258,436,951,224 -
/dev/sda24 3,695,955,742,872,046,9084,561,928,726,501,845,776865,972,983,629,798,869 -
/dev/sda25 1,297,460,286,683,948,0461,444,350,486,339,417,957146,890,199,655,469,912 -
/dev/sda26 1,228,858,248,533,131,831             0-1,228,858,248,533,131,830 -
/dev/sda121 3,189,184,846,146,487,1461,849,820,258,006,914,852-1,339,364,588,139,572,293 -
/dev/sda122 1,226,215,547,991,800,578389,781,518,734,546,300-836,434,029,257,254,277 -
/dev/sda123 3,851,660,168,574,583,4654,046,215,657,583,031,556194,555,489,008,448,092 -
/dev/sda124 1,197,460,980,174,153,341699,103,965,005,093,246-498,357,015,169,060,094 -

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 750.2 GB, 750153367552 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91200 cylinders, total 1465143296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1               2,048 1,465,143,295 1,465,141,248   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              iso9660    Ubuntu 11.04 amd64
/dev/loop1                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        E814B55B14B52E06                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        01CD-023B                              vfat       HP_RECOVERY
/dev/sdb1        7836F22A36F1E8D0                       ntfs       Elements

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop1       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /mnt                     fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)


================================ sda2/boot.ini: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[boot loader]
timeout=0
default=C:\CMDCONS\BOOTSECT.DAT
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /fastdetect
C:\CMDCONS\BOOTSECT.DAT="Microsoft Windows Recovery Console" /cmdcons
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
c104043000e9b9040dff24b580010100
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
46313020746f20737461727420746865
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
65727920706172746974696f6e207761
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
727920706172746974696f6e0d0a0000
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
000f84e5f7668b162404e82804744066
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
ce01e8dc038bfe66391624047505e8d9
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
0345086603f0e881030bd2740333d240
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
bece01e8db0287fec645041266895508
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
01f60634010175078b363b01e854f5e8
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
313825740ffec03865107408fec03824
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
02f60634014074088bfdbece01e85101
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
263401f9e894f30f858ef4e8e201e8ec
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
f7e960f35245434f5645525966606633
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
660faf1e00106603dac3668b0e001066
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
8bfd386d04740583c710e2f6c36660c6
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
04ebf132c0b91000f3aac3bf0c04ebf3
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
02662bc1660fb71e0e02662bc366031e
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
f4b40ebb0700b901003c08751381ff25
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
534f465448494e4b90653f62011b0100
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
0b050900027777772e68702e636f6d00
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
d441a0f5030003000ecb744a08bb3746
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
f8579a116b4a7aa931cde97a4b9b5c09
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
7229990415b77c0a1970e7e824237a3a
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
afb6e34d6b4bd8c7c0eada19a9786cc3
Unknown BootLoader on sda1/Wubi

00000000  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |0000000000000000|
*
00000200

Unknown BootLoader on sda2

00000000  e9 a7 00 52 45 43 4f 56  45 52 59 00 02 08 20 00  |...RECOVERY... .|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 f0 00 7f b9 f4 11  |........?.......|
00000020  8c cd ac 00 1e 2b 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.....+..........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 3b 02 cd 01 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |..);...         |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 8b d0 c1 e2 02 80  |  FAT32   ......|
00000060  e6 01 66 c1 e8 07 66 3b  46 f8 74 2a 66 89 46 f8  |..f...f;F.t*f.F.|
00000070  66 03 46 f4 66 0f b6 5e  28 80 e3 0f 74 0f 3a 5e  |f.F.f..^(...t.:^|
00000080  10 0f 83 90 00 66 0f af  5e 24 66 03 c3 bb e0 07  |.....f..^$f.....|
00000090  b9 01 00 e8 cf 00 8b da  66 8b 87 00 7e 66 25 ff  |........f...~f%.|
000000a0  ff ff 0f 66 3d f8 ff ff  0f c3 33 c9 8e d9 8e c1  |...f=.....3.....|
000000b0  8e d1 66 bc f4 7b 00 00  bd 00 7c 66 0f b6 46 10  |..f..{....|f..F.|
000000c0  66 f7 66 24 66 0f b7 56  0e 66 03 56 1c 66 89 56  |f.f$f..V.f.V.f.V|
000000d0  f4 66 03 c2 66 89 46 fc  66 c7 46 f8 ff ff ff ff  |.f..f.F.f.F.....|
000000e0  66 8b 46 2c 66 50 e8 af  00 bb 70 00 b9 01 00 e8  |f.F,fP....p.....|
000000f0  73 00 bf 00 07 b1 0b be  a9 7d f3 a6 74 2a 03 f9  |s........}..t*..|
00000100  83 c7 15 81 ff 00 09 72  ec 66 40 4a 75 db 66 58  |.......r.f@Ju.fX|
00000110  e8 47 ff 72 cf be b4 7d  ac 84 c0 74 09 b4 0e bb  |.G.r...}...t....|
00000120  07 00 cd 10 eb f2 cd 19  66 58 ff 75 09 ff 75 0f  |........fX.u..u.|
00000130  66 58 bb 00 20 66 83 f8  02 72 da 66 3d f8 ff ff  |fX.. f...r.f=...|
00000140  0f 73 d2 66 50 e8 50 00  0f b6 4e 0d e8 16 00 c1  |.s.fP.P...N.....|
00000150  e1 05 03 d9 66 58 53 e8  00 ff 5b 72 d8 8a 56 40  |....fXS...[r..V@|
00000160  ea 00 00 00 20 66 60 66  6a 00 66 50 53 6a 00 66  |.... f`fj.fPSj.f|
00000170  68 10 00 01 00 8b f4 b8  00 42 8a 56 40 cd 13 be  |h........B.V@...|
00000180  c7 7d 72 94 67 83 44 24  06 20 66 67 ff 44 24 08  |.}r.g.D$. fg.D$.|
00000190  e2 e3 83 c4 10 66 61 c3  66 48 66 48 66 0f b6 56  |.....fa.fHfHf..V|
000001a0  0d 66 f7 e2 66 03 46 fc  c3 4e 54 4c 44 52 20 20  |.f..f.F..NTLDR  |
000001b0  20 20 20 20 0d 0a 4e 6f  20 53 79 73 74 65 6d 20  |    ..No System |
000001c0  44 69 73 6b 20 6f 72 0d  0a 44 69 73 6b 20 49 2f  |Disk or..Disk I/|
000001d0  4f 20 65 72 72 6f 72 0d  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 61  |O error..Press a|
000001e0  20 6b 65 79 20 74 6f 20  72 65 73 74 61 72 74 0d  | key to restart.|
000001f0  0a 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

umount: /isodevice: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Comment: It looks like your Wubi installation is broken (see *sda1/Wubi* section). I would check the downloaded image of Wubi and reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a bogus/broken GPT.  Unless you are supposed to be using GPT, then you should remove the bogus GPT and just use the standard msdos partition table.  You should be able to use `gdisk` for this.